# Cannot calculate high number of iterations like 1,000,000,000

Tags: java, math, overflow

This code calculates the function f(x) = -1 + 2 + -3 + 4 + ... + (( - 1)^n)*n
But when the input(n) is too big, like 1000000000, java doesn't display an output.

What can I do to solve this problem?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculating_function {
    public static void main(String[] args) {



        Scanner input_taker = new Scanner(System.in);

        String n_string = input_taker.nextLine();
        long n = Long.parseLong(n_string);



        System.out.println(fonk(n));


    }

    public static long fonk(long n) {
        long total = 0;
        for(long i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

            total += (long)Math.pow(-1, i) * i; 
        }
        return total;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by *doesn't give an output.*

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: When the input is 1000000000, can't get an output.

Comment: My question is that, what can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you get an overflow exception or does the process terminate with no further output? Please clarify

Comment: It doesn't terminate. Runs forever.

Comment: How long does it take for 100, 10000, 10000000, 100000000? Is there a pattern which just means that for 1000000000 it will take a year but not forever?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to solve this using a loop?

Comment: Can you solve it without a loop?

Comment: @Jon Cokisler Yes, observe that f(n) = n/2 for any even n, and then you just need to account for what to do in the case where n is odd.

Comment: @VeeArr Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As the value of `i` increases, your exponent calculation `Math.pow(-1, i)` will take longer and longer to calculate.

As you're using `Math.pow(-1, i)` to simply swap the sign, you can optimize it as `Math.pow(-1, i%2)`. Better yet, map the multiplier to the values 1 and -1 and use `i%2` as your key.

Additionally, you are risking overflows as your total has an upper bound of `500,000,000,000,000,000` so use BigInteger instead to store the total.